# Django: annotate ranking from related objects

Tags: django, orm, relational-database

the models:

```
class Competition(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Playlist(TimeStampedModel):
    competition = models.OneToOneField(Competition, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='playlist')

class Entry(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    by = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Vote(TimeStampedModel):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="votes")
    score = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_vote_value])

class PlaylistEntry(TimeStampedModel):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='entries')
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='playlistentries')
```

A Competition has one playlist. A Competition playlist has many PlaylistEntry. A PlaylistEntry is one Entry. One Entry can have multiple Vote.

What I was able to achieve: Votes for entries counted.
What I need to achieve: Ranking for each Playlist.

The code I am using now:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ctx["compos"] = Playlist.objects \
        .filter(competition__hidden_in_results=False) \
        .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            "entries",
            PlaylistEntry.objects
                .select_related("entry")
                .annotate(score=Sum("entry__votes__score"))
                .annotate(rank=Window(expression=Rank(), order_by=F('score').desc()))
                .annotate(overall_rank=Window(expression=Rank(), order_by=F('score').desc()))
                .all(),
            to_attr="compo_entries"
        )) \
        .select_related("competition") \
        .order_by("competition__results_play_order")
    return ctx
```

This gives me Sum of votes for each Entry as I want. It also gives me a ranking as a total in all PlayList. I would need a ranking per Playlist

Current output:

```
Playlist Item 1     Rank    Overall     Score   
entry               113.    113.        196     
entry               124.    124.        178     
Playlist Item 2     Rank    Overall     Score   
entry               56.     56.         336     
entry               62.     62.         323
```

What I would like:

```
Playlist Item 1     Rank    Overall     Score   
entry               1.      113.        196     
entry               2.      124.        178     
Playlist Item 2     Rank    Overall     Score   
entry               1.      56.         336     
entry               2.      62.         323
```

Answer (score 0):

the aswer was to add `partition_by` keyword in to the mix:

```
.annotate(rank=Window(expression=Rank(), partition_by=[F('playlist')], order_by=F('score').desc()))
```

Massive thanks to FunkyBob in irc for this